# Can I set a default table space for Index and Tables? 

Tags: oracle, indexing

Currently by default create table and index DDLs will place tables in `MYDB_DATA_TABLE_SPACE`, I would like to specify a different default table space for indexes from table data so that I do not have to always explicitly mention that in my create index DDL. Is this possible?

Current:

```
Table -> MYDB_DATA_TABLE_SPACE
```

Required:

```
Table -> MYDB_DATA_TABLE_SPACE
Index -> MYDB_INDX_TABLE_SPACE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do that.

A default tablespace may be set per user, but it applies to all segment creation:  tables, indexes, materialized views, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

You can't specify a different default tablespace for indexes and for tables.  Each user only gets one default tablespace.

Hopefully, you're not trying to maintain separate tablespaces for performance reasons.  There is a relatively common myth that you can improve performance by storing data and indexes in separate tablespaces.  I'm personally not a big fan of putting indexes and data in different tablespaces-- there are no performance differences, it is terribly unlikely that you could run the application without the index tablespace so there aren't any recoverability benefits.  I understand that it can appeal to some folks sense of organization so I don't object categorically.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: I agree with you, there is no reason for doing so, other than housekeeping i guess.

Comment: Some sources - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2187770?tstart=0 with other links...

Comment: what about a different tablespace per disk? (if you're not using ASM)